# when i use ng-options why my selected doesn't have value

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm a beginner for [angularJS](https://angularjs.org/) when I practice [angularJS](https://angularjs.org/) I got a problem.

The problem is when I try to use `ng-options` I don't see any selected in my browser.

This is my code:

```
<div ng-controller="ShopController as shopCtrl">
    <div ng-repeat="products in shopCtrl.product"
        ng-hide="shopCtrl.isStartSell(products)">
            <h1>{{ products.name}}</h1>
            <span>{{products.p}}</span>
    </div>

    <select ng-model="shopCtrl.selectedProduct"
            ng-options="product.name for product in shopCtrl.products"></select>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.0-beta.1/angular.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    (function(){
        angular.module('ShoppingMall', []);

        angular.module('ShoppingMall')
                .controller('ShopController',function(){
                var self = this;

                this.product =[{
                    name: 'test01',
                    p: 1795,
                    description:'xxxxfff',
                    startSellTime:'2015-08-31 23:15:00'
                },{
                    name: 'test02',
                    p: 1790,
                    description:'xxxxfff2',
                    startSellTime:'2014-09-20 23:15:00'
                },{
                    name: 'test03',
                    p: 1793,
                    description:'xxxxfff2',
                    startSellTime:'2004-07-31 23:15:00'
                }]

                self.selectedProduct;

                self.isStartSell = function(product){
                    var startSell = new Date(product.startSellTime);
                    var currentSellTime = new Date();

                    return startSell > currentSellTime;
                }
                });
    })();
</script>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change

```
ng-options="product.name for product in shopCtrl.products"
```

to

```
ng-options="product.name for product in shopCtrl.product"
```

(remove the final 's').